# How to do ( figure and text)

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

How do I place the figure aligned with the text?

```
\begin{tabular}{cc} 
\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{IFSPMTO} & \begin{tabular}{cc}\hline \textbf{Instituto Federal de Educação Ciência e Tecnologia}\\ 
\textbf{ \bf 1$^{\underline a}$ Avaliação de Estatística Básica - Licenciatura em Química}\\ 
\textbf{Professor: Rodrigo Dantas de Lucas - Digão} \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}% 
\end{tabular} 
\textbf{Aluno:} \hspace{7cm} \textbf{RA:}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I voted for `Looks OK` to give the OP time to improve the post

Comment: Use \raisebox{-\height}{...} on the image.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I got you right as you have not give so much information. But maybe you have been searching for the `[b]` parameter of the `tabular` environment.

Like it stands now, it is too wide for the page, but as I do not know your `documentclass` and margin settings, I just leave it as it is.

```
% arara: pdflatex    

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}} 
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{IFSPMTO} & 
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}\toprule \textbf{Instituto Federal de Educação Ciência e Tecnologia}\\ 
        \textbf{ \bf 1$^{\underline a}$ Avaliação de Estatística Básica - Licenciatura em Química}\\ 
        \textbf{Professor: Rodrigo Dantas de Lucas - Digão} \\ 
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular} 
\end{tabular} 
\textbf{Aluno:} \hspace{7cm} \textbf{RA:}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the package wrapfig like this:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{fig}
\end{center}
\caption{}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: Please, please, do not post only fragments of code... it's tedious for others to verify it as solution

Comment: \begin{tabular}{cc}

 \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{IFSPMTO}
&
 \begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
  \textbf{Instituto Federal de Educação Ciência e Tecnologia}\\
 \textbf{ \bf 1$^{\underline a}$ Avaliação de Estatística Básica - Licenciatura em Química}\\
\textbf{Professor: Rodrigo Dantas de Lucas - Digão} \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}%
 
\end{tabular}


\textbf{Aluno:} \hspace{7cm} \textbf{RA:}

Comment: MWE belong to question, not to comment :-), and it start width `\documentclass{...} <necessary packages> \begin{document} <your code> \end{document}`